# Replace string between two words with the content of another text file

Tags: regex, sed, textedit

I am bit new to sed and regex.

I was trying to edit a text file, where I want to replace the contents between two keywords in the first file with the entire contents of another text file

it should like this -

```
keyword1 inbetweenstuff keyword2
```

to this

```
keyword1 textfromfile2 keyword2
```

I was trying this command, but no luck

```
sed -i 's/(keyword1).*(keyword2)/\1 contentsoffile2 \2/g' file1.txt
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to use the wrong tool. sed is for simple substitutions on individual lines (`s/old/new/`), that is all. For anything more interesting you should be using awk.

With GNU awk for multi-char RS, gensub(), and the 3rd arg for match():

```
$ cat file1
keyword1 IN BETWEEN
STUFF ON
ONE OR MORE
LINES keyword2

$ cat file2
NOW IS
THE WINTER OF
OUR DISCONTENT

$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { RS="^$"; ORS="" }
NR==FNR { new = gensub(/\n$/,"",""); next }
match($0,/(.*keyword1 ).*( keyword2.*)/,a) { print a[1] new a[2] }

$ awk -f tst.awk file2 file1
keyword1 NOW IS
THE WINTER OF
OUR DISCONTENT keyword2
```

Note that the above treats the contents of `file2` as a literal string so the contents of "file2" can be anything. Try any of the sed solutions if "file2" contains an `&`, for example (or `\1` or `/` or ...). It also doesn't care how many lines are in file2 or how many lines are between the keywords in file1.

Comment: hmm, and will it maintain the format of file2 ? Its a multi-line file, which newline characters at regulars intervals...

Comment: Yes, all it will do to file2 is deliberately remove the final newline if present so it precisely fits in between the file1 keywords.

Answer (score 1):

Okey here is a ready to use solution:

```
$ sed -i "s/\(keyword1\).*\(keyword2\)/\1 `cat file2` \2/g" file1
```

It reads from `file2` and replaces text between two keywords inside `file1` (works only if contents in `file2` is not multiline).

Comment: file2 is multiline unfortunately.

Comment: Than you want something more advanced as @EdMorton's answer for example.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -e '/keyword1\s*/{:a;/\s*keyword2/!{N;ba};s/\n//g;s/keyword1\s*/&\n/;s/\s*keyword2/\n&/;P;e cat inserted_file' -e 's/.*\n//}' file
```

This looks for `keyword1` and keeps that line and perhaps subsequent lines upto `keyword2` in the pattern space. Then all newlines are deleted and newlines inserted after `keyword1` and before `keyword2`. The part line before `keyword1` is then printed, followed by the `inserted_file` and lastly then from `keyword2` to the end of its line.

This will surround the `inserted_file` with newlines. If these are not required then post process that file with:

```
sed -r 'N;s/(keyword1\s*)\n/\1/;s/\n(\s*keyword2)/\1/;P;D' new_file
```